# Exercise probabilistic kernel and measure

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

If I have a kernel like this: $K(x,B)=1_B \circ h(x)$ and a function $f$ where $h,f$ are two positive and measurable function with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra, and I want to proof that $K f=f \circ h$, can I do this:
Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of increasing simply function that converge to $f$, so $Kf_n=K\left(\sum_{i\in I}a_i 1_{A_i}\right)=\sum_{i\in I}a_i K(x,A_i)=a_j$ if $h(x) \in A_j$ but $f_n \circ h=\sum_{i\in I}a_i 1_{A_i}(h(x))=a_j$ then $Kf=f_n \circ h$ and so I can estend this fact to $f$ so $K f=f \circ h$?

Comment: In case you are still interested in an answer here, your question is completely unclear.

Comment: I try to explain.
If you have a probabilistic kernel you can define this operation with function: $K f(x)=\int f(y) K(x,dy)$ where $K(x,dy)$ it's a measure fixed a point x. So I want to prof that with that special kernel $K=1_B \circ h(x)$, I have that $K f=f \circ h$

Comment: I see. Here $\circ$ is a superposition in both cases?

Comment: It's a simple composition of function

Comment: Am I being clear now?

Comment: More directly, note that $K(x,\ )$ is the Dirac measure $\delta_{h(x)}$ at $h(x)$ hence $Kf(x)=\int f(y)K(x,dy)$ is $\int fd\delta_{h(x)}=f(h(x))$, qed.

Comment: Yes, $lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\delta_{h(x)}B(y,r)=1$ only if $y=h(x)$